# how to solve django.db.utils.IntegrityError?

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, loaddata

I am trying to migrate django sqlite database to mysql. So first I dumpdata by running

```
python manage.py dumpdata > db.json
```

after that I changed

```
setting.py
```

after this I created database at mysql and migrate

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and open shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

write

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

but when I run

```
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

I got error like this

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-Downloads' for key 'filer_folder.filer_folder_parent_id_name_bc773258_uniq'")
............
.............
............
...........
..........
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/var/www/html/Planning/SampleTemplate/db.json': Could not load filer.Folder(pk=23): (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-Downloads' for key 'filer_folder.filer_folder_parent_id_name_bc773258_uniq'")
```

Comment: the json has multiple identical keys for filer_folder_parent_id_name_bc773258_uniq maybe it isn't that unique as you thought

Comment: could you please tell me how to solve that

Comment: Is it possible that one of your migrations inserts some data?  Try running `python manage.py flush` to delete all data in your DB before importing? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: maybe a deleteng for all rows would help.